# How to use messaging with pyramid_sockjs?

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, pyramid, gevent-socketio

I'm building a Pyramid application using [pyramid_sockjs](https://github.com/fafhrd91/pyramid_sockjs). This app needs to react to incoming messages from redis pub/sub or rabbitmq. Where am I supposed to plug in the logic to listen to the messaging system and react by sending messages to sockjs clients?

I have found this [link for socket.io](http://blog.abourget.net/2011/3/31/new-and-hot-part-6-redis-publish-and-subscribe/), and I would like to do the same with sockjs and Pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you setup a pyramid config with `config.include('pyramd_sockjs')` followed by `config.add_sockjs_route()`. the general difficulty here is to figure out how to get hold of the app's current sockjs-sessions. i'm thinking of three scenarios:

1. usually you react to messages from within you own subclass of `pyramid_sockjs.session.Session` as shown in the [chat example](https://github.com/fafhrd91/pyramid_sockjs/blob/master/examples/chat.py).
2. broadcasting messages from within one of your views is just as easy by calling `request.get_sockjs_manager().broadcast(some_message)`
3. however, if you're neither inside the sockjs-messaging- nor the http-request-cycle like in your case, then you have to resort to pyramid's `registry` where all addons leave their traces.

at [minute 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=hrpO2pzzMUE#t=301) in your video you would write something like this:

```
def listener():
    r = redis.Redis()
    r.subscribe(['foo'])
    for msg in r.listen():
        from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry
        get_current_registry().__sockjs_managers__[''].broadcast(msg)
```

to explain the above hack:

- `get_current_registry` is usually [discouraged](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/threadlocal.html) because it's hard to test your code. it returns the current request's or the global registry - a central core-component of pyramid.
- for `__sockjs_managers__` pyramid_sockjs should have provided a getter on the registry as it did for the `request`.
- the empty string is the pyramid_sockjs' default `name` attribute (pass as kw to `add_sockjs_route` to change it)

unfortunately pyramid_sockjs doesn't provide "rooms" yet so your messages will be broadcasted to all connected clients without any prior filter mechanisms. to help that you might want to subclass `pyramid_sockjs.session.Session` and `.SessionManager`. (please tell if you do!)